# use a jar in a java class through jython

Tags: java, import, jar, jython

I want to use my java class ( lets call it *myclass.java*) in jython and *myclass.java* uses a .jar library. I compiled the myclass using the .jar library as classpath. 
But when I import myclass in jython , it didn't recognize classes from the jar.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a library to compile your Java class, you also need the library JAR file in the classpath when using your Jython classes.

Just put the JAR in Jython's classpath, and it should work.